# Show that $M_{2k}(\Gamma(1))=\left\langle G_{4}^{\alpha}G_{6}^{\beta}: 3\alpha+2\beta=k\right\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-forms

> Show that $$M_{2k}(\Gamma(1))=\left\langle G_{4}^{\alpha}G_{6}^{\beta}: 3\alpha+2\beta=k\right\rangle$$
>   where $\Gamma(1)= SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z})$ and $M_{2k}$ is the set of modular forms of weight $2k$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

I try to prove it since we have $$\Delta(z)=\frac{1}{1728}(\Delta_{4}(z)^3-\Delta_{6}(z)^2),$$
hence $\Gamma_{1}$ is a polymomial in $E_{4}$ and $E_{6}$ and $f(z)$ be a modular form of weight $\forall 2k$ ($k\geq 2$), with Fourier expansioin $$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}e^{2\pi i n z}.$$

But how about the $\Gamma(1)$?

I think it is useful: we may consider the may $$M_{k-12}(\Gamma (1))\rightarrow M_{k}(\Gamma (1)),$$
where we have $M_{12}(\Gamma (1))=\left\langle G_{12}, \Delta\right\rangle$.

Comment: It is a straightforward counting using the following formula and the fact every modular forms of weight $\leq 12$ is a polynomial of $G_6, G_4$: $$\sum v_P + \frac{1}{2} v_i + \frac{1}{3} v_\rho + v_\infty = \frac{2k}{12}$$ where $\rho = e^{2\pi i/3}$, do you recognize it?

Comment: @pisco Sorry, I know this formula, but I do not know how to use this formula to show $M_{2k}(\Gamma(1))=<G_{4}^{\alpha}G_{6}^{\beta}: \alpha+\beta=k>$?

Comment: @pisco I am sorry, it is $3\alpha+2\beta =k$.

Comment: Please don't use comparison operators ($<$ and $>$) for brackets, we have $\langle$ `\langle` and $\rangle$ `\rangle` for that. Spread the word.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can determine the modular forms of weight $<12$ using above formula. 
$$\sum v_P + \frac{1}{2} v_i + \frac{1}{3} v_\rho + v_\infty = \frac{2k}{12}$$
They are: constants, $G_4$, $G_6$, $G_4^2$, $G_4G_6$, with weight $0,4,6,8,10$ respectively.

Then use induction: every weight $2k$ modular form $f$ can be made into a cusp form by $f_1 = f - c G_{2k}$ for some constant $c$, so $f_1 / \Delta$ is a modular form of weight $2k-12$.

Comment: Sorry, is it related to the $\left\langle G_{4}^{\alpha}G_{6}^{\beta}: 3\alpha+2\beta=k\right\rangle$?

Comment: @Tinzoe-Yui   Yes. I am indeed answering your question. Could you say which part you have trouble understanding at?

Comment: Do you mean we assume $f=\sum_{3\alpha+2\beta=k} G_{4}^{\alpha}G_{6}^{\beta} $, then use the induction to $f_{1}/\Delta$(with $2k$ replaced by $2k-12$?